# How to transition from viewcontroller to other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsarray, uiviewanimation

I have two viewcontrollers, there is a button in the firstviewcontroller, when I click this button, it will switch the viewcontroller from first to second

```
[self transitionFromViewController:firstVC
                  toViewController:secondVC
                          duration:0.3
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                        animations:nil
                        completion:nil];
```

but it will crash with the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Children view controllers (null) and (null) must have a common parent view controller when calling -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]

I check the docs of `transitionFromViewController:firstVC`, it seems right, so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, it says your view controllers are both `null` in your error log. Fix that. Then you can worry about transitioning.. Read your error logs properly..

You need a container controller such that the two controllers you want to transition between is a child of the container (parent controller)..

For example, to transition between two controllers, both have to be a child of a common parent controller. Then you can call transition to transition between them. Another option is to have ONE as the child at any given time, transition to another by adding it as a child and remove the original.

Example of controller swapping below (only one child at a time):

**Objective-C:**

```
@interface ContainerController : UIViewController {
    UIViewController *_currentController;
}
@end

@implementation ContainerController


- (void)switchToViewController:(UIViewController *)controller duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [controller.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    if (_currentController) {
        [_currentController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [self addChildViewController:controller];

        [self transitionFromViewController:_currentController toViewController:controller duration:duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{

            //Additional animations here..

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [_currentController removeFromParentViewController];
            [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            [_currentController.view removeFromSuperview];
            _currentController = controller;
        }];
    }
    else {
        [self addChildViewController:controller];
        [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
        [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        _currentController = controller;
    }
}
@end
```

**Swift 4:**

```
class ContainerController : UIViewController {
    private var currentController: UIViewController?

    func switchToController(controller: UIViewController, duration: TimeInterval) {
        controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds

        if let currentController = self.currentController {
            currentController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            self.addChildViewController(controller)

            self.transition(from: currentController, to: controller, duration: duration, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

                //Additional Animations here..

            }) { (completedTransition) in
                currentController.removeFromParentViewController()
                controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
                currentController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.currentController = controller
            }
        }
        else {
            self.addChildViewController(controller)
            self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
            controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            self.currentController = controller
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good. But the `removeFromSuperview` is unnecessary, too (as `transitionFromViewController` does that for us).

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

1. The `transition` method is intended for "view controller containment" only, where you have a parent view controller with a child view controller that is managing some subview within the parent view controller's view. Are you really doing view controller containment?

   If you're not doing containment and only want to transition from one view controller to another, use [`showViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621377-showviewcontroller?language=objc), [`presentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller?language=objc), [`pushViewcontroller`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller?language=objc) on your `navigationController`, or a segue to transition from one to another.
2. That having been said, even if you intended to do view controller containment, your error message suggests that `firstVC` and `secondVC` are `nil`, your assignment of those variables do not appear to be correct. Make sure that

   - both `firstVC` and `secondVC` are not `nil`;
   - `firstVC` is the child view controller whose view is currently in the parent view controller's view hierarchy; and
   - `secondVC` has been added as a child view controller before you call `transition`.
3. Note that the `animations` block must not be omitted. If you don't want to do any additional animation, supply an empty block, not `nil`.